# Localhost doesnt show my files in /var/www/html

Tags: php, localhost, apache2

When i try to get into my localhost folder I get this

[image]

I tried to uninstall and reinstall apache2 but nothing changed
i restarted apache2 and reloaded it nothing
i can access php myadmin and also mysql

however localhost stays 'empty' but i have folders in var/www/html

http://local.server.ip gives me this error
bash: http://local.server.ip: No such file or directory

```
    [Fri Nov 22 00:07:53.655847 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21559] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 00:07:53.655912 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21559] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 22 01:15:05.406145 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21559] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Nov 22 01:15:05.436629 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21559] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 01:15:05.436640 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21559] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 22 01:16:52.092655 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21559] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Nov 22 01:16:52.129474 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21559] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 01:16:52.129490 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21559] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 22 01:30:50.708402 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21559] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 22 01:31:02.848171 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27340] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 01:31:02.848207 2019] [core:notice] [pid 27340] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 22 01:31:20.409265 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27340] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 22 01:34:21.641232 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28568] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 01:34:21.641268 2019] [core:notice] [pid 28568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 22 01:34:46.704722 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28568] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Nov 22 01:34:46.725762 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28568] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 01:34:46.725772 2019] [core:notice] [pid 28568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 22 02:08:30.892405 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28568] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 22 02:08:30.984621 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30975] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 02:08:30.984671 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30975] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

[image]

grep -inRH "ServerName " /etc/apache2/ | grep "\s#"*
  [image]

I added 
ServerName = Localhost

and 
grep -inRH "ServerName " /etc/apache2/ | grep "\s#"*

gives me this output
i used a virtuell host before

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a file, not just folders in `/var/www/html`. Make sure the file is readable by the Apache process too. Try putting a file named `index.html` there, run `chmod a+r /var/www/html/index.html` and then browse to localhost again - you should see the contents of your file then

Comment: i have files and folders in the html folder

Comment: Can you run `ls -l /var/www/html` and post it here? Also, check the Apache logs for errors and include them here if you see any (likely /var/log/apache2/error.log)

Comment: [Fri Nov 22 00:07:53.655847 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21559] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 22 00:07:53.655912 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21559] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 22 01:15:05.406145 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21559] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: Yes I would not expect you to, but I would need to see the output of that command to help you further

Comment: Please add your above comment as part of your question instead of a comment

Comment: that is the only error i get 
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: OK, are you able to include the output of the ls command as part of your answer or no?

Comment: Ok but can you include the output of running `ls -l /var/www/html` please

Comment: i have added the output

Comment: i added some more infos

Comment: you just installad apache, with no other configuration ? You didn't add some virtual host configuration ? Can you display you sites-enabled configuration files ?